# How to reduce the amount of objects created parsing dataset?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, datarow

Dataset consists of a table of two columns. Table name=Project. One column name=Name, other column name=Resource. There are multiple repetitive project names.

```
var dataset = FakeDataset.CreateDataset();
        var projectList = new List<Project>();

        foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
            {
                projectList.Add(new Project { Name = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"]), Resource = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Resource"]) });
            }
        }
```

Now I am creating a Project object every time for a single project Name in the dataset. What I want is - to create Project object only for unique project Name in dataset. I am a beginner so would be nice a simple solution.

Comment: What makes you think that Linq will reduce the number of object created? It is just a *different* way of doing the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested and I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but from my assumptions
you want something like this:

```
    var dataset = FakeDataset.CreateDataset();
                    var projectList = new List<Project>();

                    foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
                        {
                              if(projectList.Any(Project => Project.Name == dataRow["Name"]))
                                       projectList.Add(new Project { Name = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"]), Resource = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Resource"]) });
                        }
                    }
```

---

Edit:

```
var dataset = FakeDataset.CreateDataset();
var projectList = new List<Project>();

    foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
    {
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
            {
                    if (!projectList.Any(Project => Project.Name == Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"])))
                    {
                        projectList.Add(new Project { Name = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"]), Resource = Convert.ToString(dataRow["Resource"]) });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Project p = projectList.Find(Project => Project.Name == Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"]));
                        projectList[projectList.IndexOf(p)].Resource += "\r\n" + Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"]);
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: What is your code suppose to do? I mean whats the logic in if statement?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to stop adding any Projects with duplicate names. The if statement checks if there are any Projects inside the list that have the same name that you want to add in.

Comment: I want to stop creating Project objects with duplicate names but STILL set projects Resource properties. Imagine a 2 row table. 1 row for project Name, another row for Resource. One project can have a lot of resources.  But I don't want to create Project object for every Resource. Somehow I would like to create one Project and set its Resources instead. And without LINQ if possible.

Comment: Check after the edit, uses LINQ but should work.

(not tested, can't atm, written in Notepad :/)
You should be able to fix the errors though